# Batch uploading images into Google Earth

Tags: google-earth, image, batch

I am looking to visualize images on Google Earth. I have a couple thousand images that I would like to batch upload in order to verify results from a field study. I have a KMZ file with placemarks where the ID field is a image name that was taken in that location.

What I would like to be able to do is have some way of batch loading each image into the placemark (similar to the manual way of doing it by opening placemark properties and adding a local image to the placemark). I also have the images georeferenced (which I did with exiftools) if there is some easier way to upload them directly instead of using the placemark route.

Comment: Alternative "road" with QGIS https://opengislab.com/blog/2020/8/23/mapping-and-viewing-geotagged-photos-in-qgis

Comment: How do you want to view the images? In the info-balloons on your placemarks? Or as ground overlays?  When you say your images are "georeferenced", do you mean that they have just one point on the ground (like a GPS location where the photo was taken), or are they fully georeferenced images (like aerial photos with 3+ reference points or N/S/E/W bounds) to allow them to be laid down over the terrain?  Also, do you have a preference for using Google Earth Pro (desktop) or Google Earth 9 (web & mobile)?